# Починить adb доступ к планшету

Tags: android, adb

Произошла такая ерунда, до моих манипуляций всё работало идеально, adb работал, даже linux удавалось запустить. Решил я bootloader разблокировать, включил девайс держа громкость -, и он похоже запустился в режиме fastboot. И после этого при попытке подключить adb пишет:

```
no permissions (user in plugdev group; are your udev rules wrong?);
```

Эта команда тоже не помогла.

```
flutter doctor
```

Его вывод такой.

```
Error retrieving device properties for ro.product.cpu.abi:
```

Я уже сдался и решил попросить помощи, может кто решал. Помогите пожалуйста.

Есть вариант - это сброс к заводским, но он меня не очень устраивает.

Comment: В русскоязычном интернете что-то не нагугливается ничего подобного. В англоязычном же: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49216585/no-permissions-user-in-plugdev-group-are-your-udev-rules-wrong, https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10330, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28704636/insufficient-permissions-for-device-in-android-studio-workspace-running-in-opens.

Comment: Со stackowerflow находил, не помогло. А вот на гитхабе не видел

Comment: Помогло, спасибо, сейчас ответ для других напишу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я решил проблему так:
Остановил adb от юзера:

```
$ adb kill-server
```

После остановил сервер рута, на всякий случай:

```
$ sudo adb kill-server
```

Потом запустил сервер от рута:

```
$ sudo adb start-server
```

И вывод команды `$ adb devices` выдал:

```
List of devices attached
XRP8NDKD1N  device
```

Запустил `$ adb shell` и попал в девайс:

```
shell@android:/ $
```